# What is textStyle in outlinedButtonTheme?

Tags: flutter

What is textStyle in outlinedButtonTheme?

```
outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
      TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
    ),
),
```

Does it define text style properties for the text in OutlinedButton? Then text color in the OutlinedButton is not a pink

```
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('sample'), // has not a pink color
),
```

Comment: There is no `textStyle` parameter on `OutlinedButtonThemeData` , flutter v2.5.3

Comment: `OutlinedButton`'s docs say: *"An outlined button is a label child displayed on a (zero elevation) Material widget. The label's Text and Icon widgets are displayed in the style's ButtonStyle.foregroundColor and the outline's weight and color are defined by ButtonStyle.side"*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
    OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: Colors.pink,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?